# Display ALL Blog Intros in Joomla Category Blog (Hide 'More Articles')

Tags: joomla, blogs, joomla-article

I would like to feature ALL blog intros in Joomla.

Currently I can post only 5 articles before it adds a "more articles" link afterward.  I want to be able to display ALL blog article intros, without this "more articles" being appended to the end.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the menu manager, select the category blog you want to change and set the parameter `#intro articles` under "Blog Layout Options" to a higher number. The default value is `5`.